# How to use rxjs Subject properly?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have defined Callback function which takes event and it is called on interaction with UI.
Event contains data about done changes.
When CallBack Function is called i have to update local storage data by data from event and send post request to server.
In some times call back function is called several times at the same times and it is expected behavior.
My problem is how not to sending sometimes several request to server but send when the last event is emitted only.

I was trying sth like this but it sends a lot of request in some cases.

```
callBackFinction: (event) => {
    this.MyService.subject.next(event);
    this.MyService.UpdateData(event);
    this.MyService.subject.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(() => {
        http.post('/url', data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Use last() operator: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/last.html

Comment: Also, it will only work when you use subject.complete(). Otherwise it's impossible to know if a value is the last on the stream.

Comment: If you need to handle cancelation of previous request when a new value arrives, so the approach is other. Use a switchmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need subject in `ngOnInit` or `constructor`. Because you will generate a new subscription when each callback, and there is not unsubscribe.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.MyService.subject.pipe(debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(data => {
    http.post('/url', data);
  });
}

callBackFinction: (event) => {
    this.MyService.subject.next(event);
    this.MyService.UpdateData(event);
}
```